# Updating SQL Table From VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a table that needs to be refreshed each time a certain macro is run.  I have the SQL query stored within the table properties.  I have tried clicking the refresh button within excel but that is not working.

Below is the sub that I wrote that (attempts) to update the query when called.

```
Sub updateTable ()

Sheets("table").Select
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("tableQueries").Range.Select
Selection.ListObject.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=True

 With ActiveSheet.ListObjects("tableQueries")
    .HeaderRowRange(1) = "Column 1"
    .HeaderRowRange(2) = "Column 2"
    .HeaderRowRange(3) = "Column 3"
    .HeaderRowRange(4) = "Column 4"
    .HeaderRowRange(5) = "Column 5"
    .HeaderRowRange(6) = "Column 6"
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Whats is the error you are getting?

Comment: I do not get an error at all. That's what's causing some of my confusion. It runs through like it's updating, but the data does not change.

Comment: Why don't you refresh the entire sheet?

Comment: I tried refreshing the entire sheet, that didn't work either

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, this is more of a comment than an answer, but I'll post it here so I can use code blocks. I haven't done SQL in Excel before, but I see two probable causes:

1. "table" isn't the sheet that "tableQueries" is on.
2. Using Select and Selection is causing you problems.

If "table" isn't the sheet "tableQueries" is on, you'd have to tell us which sheet is the correct one. But assuming it is on "table", try this code instead and see if your problem persists:

```
Sub updateTable()

ListObjects("tableQueries").QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=True

With ActiveSheet.ListObjects("tableQueries")
    .HeaderRowRange(1) = "Column 1"
    .HeaderRowRange(2) = "Column 2"
    .HeaderRowRange(3) = "Column 3"
    .HeaderRowRange(4) = "Column 4"
    .HeaderRowRange(5) = "Column 5"
    .HeaderRowRange(6) = "Column 6"
End With

End Sub
```

If that's not working, sometimes `With` can be grumpy with tables. Try this too:

```
Sub updateTable()

ListObjects("tableQueries").QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=True

ActiveSheet.ListObjects("tableQueries").HeaderRowRange(1) = "Column 1"
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("tableQueries").HeaderRowRange(2) = "Column 2"
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("tableQueries").HeaderRowRange(3) = "Column 3"
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("tableQueries").HeaderRowRange(4) = "Column 4"
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("tableQueries").HeaderRowRange(5) = "Column 5"
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("tableQueries").HeaderRowRange(6) = "Column 6"

End Sub
```

Comment: "table" is the sheet that contains "tableQueries"

For your first solution, it throws an error unless you have "ActiveSheet.ListObjects(...." Otherwise this does not update the table.

I got rid of the with statement and ran it as per your second example, again no update of the data.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to refresh the entire sheet and not just the table, then below two line should do the trick. Put first line before you run your certain macro and second line after your macro.

```
1. ActiveSheet.EnableCalculation = False  'Before your macro
2. ActiveSheet.EnableCalculation = True   'After your macro
```

For example:

```
Sub refreshSheet()
    ActiveSheet.EnableCalculation = False
    'Call your sub here  <-----
    ActiveSheet.EnableCalculation = True
End Sub
```

Comment: I would like to just refresh the table.  However, this does not fresh the table either.